# extracting the zip file name from file path

Tags: java

I am getting an file name in string as shown below ..

```
File f = generateZipForAFile(FilePath, filetimeCreation);
```

Which is returning as found upon inspection

```
C:\App\Split\top\log\abcFeed_2013-09-03_2013-09-03_091239.zip
```

Now I need to take out the zip file name and the zip file name will be dynamcic, zip file name can change also, but the folder location would be the same so please advise the logic to extract the file name

Comment: Did you even take a look at the Javadoc from the File class ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `getName()`

```
String name = f.getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the location string with `\\` and get the last index(`strs.length-1`) of splitted string. You'll get the file name with extension.

If you need name without extension then split it again with `\\.` and take the 0th index.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are getting file object then first convert into String then use substring function.
Ex:

```
File f1=new File("C:\\App\\Split\\top\\log\\abcFeed_2013-09-03_2013-09-03_091239.zip");
            String str=f1.toString();

            String s=str.substring(21);
            System.out.println(s);
```

OR if you are getting file name as string then u can directly use substring.